# How to get sum of list value and after unselect value shoud substract in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here in this screen there are two tabs 1.INVOICE SPECIFIC and 2.AD-HOC .
Now In 1.Invoice SPECIFIC I am maping array ("above array) value with checkbox ,there are some amout "data.TransactionAmount" I have to calculate the sum of all and send to next screen,
but if I uncheck any of the list amount should minus .Like there are 3 values - 1050 ,1050,150 =3150 and if I unchecked single value then it should be 1050+1050=2100.
If i am uncheking single list all list is getting unchecked .
2. Ad Hoc , here I  can enter any digint and send in button press , but value is not updating ,1 tab value is going .
Please help , Thanks ,
Below link is refrence what i am implementing .

https://xd.adobe.com/view/d733da48-5d0c-47ca-7ded-6fc8f0f609cf-a102/screen/37cb15c6-b56a-4b98-8612-e9b86d0dd34c/Android-Mobile-147/?fullscreen

```
// Below is the array value 
financialTransactionDetail: Array(3)
0:
AdjustedAmount: "0"
NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
TransactionAmount: 1050
1:
AdjustedAmount: "0"
NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
TransactionAmount: 1050
2:
AdjustedAmount: "0"
NetTransactionAmount: "1050"
Status: "Unpaid"
TransactionAmount: 1050

__typename: "FinancialTransactionDetail"

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Button, Card, CardItem, CheckBox, Text, View, Item, Input, Tab, Tabs, Container } from 'native-base';
import Header from '../../ui/header';
import BG from '../../../images/bg.jpg';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { RegularText, SmallText } from '../../ui/text';

const styles = {
  container: {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  imgBG:{
    width: '100%'
  },
  dataContainer:{
    backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'100%', flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'
  },
  checkBox : {paddingBottom:2}
}

class PaymentsInvoice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'Payments against invoice',
      icon: 'sim',
      mobile:this.props.navigation.state.params.customer.service.serviceNumber,
      isChecked:true,
      sum :{},
      transactionAmount :''
    }
  }
  handleChange(){
    this.setState({isChecked:!this.state.isChecked})
  }
  render() {
    let { title, icon, mobile,sum } = this.state;
    const { navigation,invoiceDetailsinfo } = this.props;
    const{financialTransactionDetail} = invoiceDetailsinfo;
    sum = financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.reduce((a, c) => { return a + c.TransactionAmount}, 0);
       console.log('sum: ', sum)

    return (
      <ImageBackground source={BG} style={styles.imgBG}>
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Header title={title} icon={icon} subtitle={mobile} navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
              <Container>
                <Tabs>
                  <Tab heading="INVOICE SPECIFIC">
                  { !_.isEmpty(financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail) && financialTransactionDetail.financialTransactionDetail.map(
                    (data, index) => {
                      return(
                        <View key={index} style={{flexDirection:'row', padding:10, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                      <View style={{paddingRight:10, marginRight:10}}>
                        <CheckBox style={styles.checkBox} color="#00678f" checked={this.state.isChecked} onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                      </View>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1, padding:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'lightgrey', borderRadius:10}}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                          {!this.state.isChecked && <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{paddingBottom:10, paddingRight:5}}/>}
                          <SmallText text="From 1-Jan-2019 to 31-Jan-2019" style={{paddingBottom:10}}/>
                        </View>
                        {this.state.isChecked && 
                        <RegularText text={`₦ ${data.TransactionAmount}`} style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                          </RegularText>
                          /* <Input
                            value={this.state.transactionAmount}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({value1:text})}
                          /> */
                        }
                      </View>
                    </View>
                      )
                    }
                  )
                  }

                  </Tab>
                  <Tab heading="AD-HOC">
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'column', padding:20}}>
                      <RegularText text="Enter Specific Amount to pay" style={{paddingBottom:10}} textColor="darkgrey"/>
                      <View>
                        <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                          <Input
                              value={this.state.sum}
                              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({sum:text})}
                            />
                        </Item>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </Tab>
                </Tabs>
              </Container>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Button full onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('PaymentOptionsContainer',sum)}>
                <Text>Receive Payment ({sum})</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
export default PaymentsInvoice;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have built sample test application for your requirements.
And it's on this repository: https://github.com/danZheng1993/sample_for_Abhigyan
Please check it